# Common part of 2 lists that contains different objects

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I got two lists, one contains `ProductDto` and another one contains `ConsumedProductDto`

```
@Builder
@Getter
@ToString
public class ProductDto {
    private final String id;
    private final String productName;
    private final Double calories;
    private final Double protein;
    private final Double fat;
    private final Double carbohydrates;
    private final Double weight;
}

@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
public class ConsumedProductDto {
    private final String username;
    private final LocalDate date;
    private final String productID;
    private final Double weight;
}
```

Now, I want to get common part of those two lists, those objects are equal if `ProductDto.id == ConsumedProductDto.productID`

I wrote that function to do that:

```
private List<ProductDto> matchingProducts(List<ProductDto> products, List<ConsumedProductDto> consumedProducts) {
        return products.stream().filter(product ->
                consumedProducts.stream()
                        .allMatch(consumedProduct ->
                              product.getId().equals(consumedProduct.getProductID())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It works, until I have two (or more)`ConsumedProductDto` with same `productID`. Then, I'm getting only one `ProductDto` back, when I want to have two (or more).

Any ideas what went wrong?
Also, I'm aware I could `@Override equals()` and check those common part with `contains()`, but is it good idea to mix 2 different classes like that?

Comment: *It works, until I have two (or more)ConsumedProductDto with same productID. Then, I'm getting only one ProductDto back, when I want to have two (or more)* ... Do you mean if there is 1 `ProductDto` with `id:xyz` and 2 `ConsumedProductDto` with `productID:xyz` then you would have the `ProductDto` 2 times in the output result? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the response to the comment, you are actually looking for multiple `ProductDto` entries in the output for multiple `ConsumedProductDto`s based on the filter condition to match such products.

Therefore, what you would be interested in would be iterating through the `consumedProductDto`s and finding any match of `productDto`s and `map` that to be collected in the eventual output. This could look like the following approach:

```
private List<ProductDto> matchingProducts(List<ProductDto> products, List<ConsumedProductDto> consumedProducts) {
    return consumedProducts.stream()
            .map(consumedProductDto -> products.stream()
                    .filter(productDto -> productDto.getId().equals(consumedProductDto.getProductID()))
                    .findAny().orElse(null))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```